# Remove SSL certificate from a project with tomcat 7

Tags: java, android, tomcat, ssl

This project located [here](http://ryanfx.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/raspberry-pi-powered-android-controlled.html) was completed with SSL. Now I need to do to this without SSL. I want to design it for a desktop (html5, websocket).

Currently I am getting this error type : http://www.guj.com.br/java/261352-reconfigurar-ssl-default-java in the android app...

Before this error explain that this type took two lines:

```
httpsurlconnection.setSSLSocketFactory(GarageSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(application));
```

and I had this error:
"Javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x74f61128: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol erro erro:140770FCSSL routines:SS23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol(external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:7660x7449ad5c:0x0000000)"

Now I'm getting the error:

```
can not be cast to com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have some SSL code left.

A `HttpsURLConnection` where you need to get rid of that `s` so it becomes a regular `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank's for answer: I have line: import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Comment: Just then I switch HttpsURLConnection by HttpURLConnection??

Comment: what you tell me about the lines: httpsurlconnection.setSSLSocketFactory (GarageSSLSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory (application)); ????

and javax.net.ssl.httpsurlconnection??